# How do I monitor the values of variables in a Java program?

Tags: java

Lets say i have a couple of loops in my Java code. To check my code for correctness, i write all the necessary variables on paper and imagine the code executing in my mind. I note their values with each step on the paper. 
Sometimes i have to use print statements also to spot errors.

Is there any software (stand alone or plugin for Eclipse IDE which I use) which can track all these things for me ?

Comment: it is called Debugger

Comment: You can run your program in Eclise in the debug mode where you can monitor each and every variable values of your code

Comment: Debug. It is a feature built into most IDEs that allow you to step through your code at user set breakpoints and check all variables at each step of the way.

Comment: See this video [how to use Debugger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeSitNPAExg)

Comment: See [Tips and Tricks for Debugging in Eclipse](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/tips-and-tricks-debugging-ecli)

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov - Thanks for the link. I am adding some info about that video. 

It uses test driven development ! :(
Link for project files took a while to find - sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsetutorial/files/3. Debugger Tutorial/Version 1.0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what the Debugger is for.  Resist the urge to write to console or file to track these values.

Spend some time learning how to use the debugger correctly, you're going to spend a lot of time using it in the future.

Note:
I think it is very positive that you instinctively came to the conslusion that a tool such as the debugger should exist.

Comment: I concur with the recommendation of learning how to use the debugger properly. I want to point out though that in 99% of the cases, it's really a question of taste as to whether one should use a debugger or logs to debug code.  Among the advantages of logs: you can keep them in your code for future reuse; sometimes with a printout of a number of events, you can more quickly identify when something starts derailing; you can look at a history of statements your printed and share it with someone, etc.   The problems that are clearly better solved with a debugger are only a minority in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

[See this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/) if you use Eclipse IDE.

Mostly all IDEs have a built in debugger which allows you to set breakpoints and step through your program line by line, viewing variable values at each step of the way.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you are after.  If you want to debug code that's not working, you can do using print statements like you do or kicking in the debugger with Eclipse.  Both methods have their advantages and limitations.

If you are looking into statistics of the content of some variables, you could use tools like http://metrics.codahale.com.

Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

Put some debug points in your code and debug the application.If you are using eclipse IDE, please try using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `assert` statement.  It will allow you to specify your knowledge in the code itself.

Note that they must explicitly be enabled when starting the JVM.